# Django UrlResolver, adding urls at runtime for testing

Tags: django, unit-testing, url, testcase

I'm looking to do some tests and I'm not really familiar with the `URLResolver` quite yet but I'd like to solve this issue quickly.

In a `TestCase`, I'd like to add a URL to the resolver so that I can then use `Client.get('/url/')` and keep it separate from `urls.py`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#urlconf-configuration

In your test:

```
class TestMyViews(TestCase):
     urls = 'myapp.test_urls'
```

This will use `myapp/test_urls.py` as the `ROOT_URLCONF`.

Comment: To visitors from the future, please note the more appropriate (for modern Django versions) answer @renskiy has added.

Answer (score 52):

Since Django 1.8 [using of `django.test.TestCase.urls` is deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.urls). You can use `django.test.utils.override_settings` instead:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.utils import override_settings

urlpatterns = [
    # custom urlconf
]

@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF=__name__)
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    pass
```

`override_settings` can be applied either to a whole class or to a particular method.

Comment: This completely overrides the urlpatterns. What if I want to add to them, instead?

Comment: @Joost You can do something like `from myapp.urls import urlpatterns as base_patterns` and then `urlpatterns = base_patterns + [<your custom patterns here>]`

Comment: I had to add self.reload_urlconf() in my test to force the reload, as well as using @override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF=__name__)

Comment: `from myapp.urls import urlpatterns as base_patterns` didn't work for me because my tests for all other URLs relied on the full paths. I had to do `my_project.urls import urlpatterns as base_patterns`. Also, because it was `my_project.urls`, I had to write the full path (e.g. `/myapp/path/to/my/view` instead of `/path/to/my/view`) in the tests.

Comment: What black magic is going on here with the `__name__` parameter? Why do I get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error if `urlpatterns` is passed in directly instead of specifying `__name__`?

Comment: I can't get this working when using the `StaticLiveServerTestCase`

Answer (score 7):

I know this was asked a while ago, but I thought I'd answer it again to offer something more complete and up-to-date.

You have two options to solve this, one is to provide your own urls file, as suggested by SystemParadox's answer:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    urls = 'my_app.test_urls'
```

The other is to monkey patch your urls. This is NOT the recommended way to deal with overriding urls but you might get into a situation where you still need it. To do this for a single test case without affecting the rest you should do it in your `setUp()` method and then cleanup in your `tearDown()` method.

```
import my_app.urls
from django.conf.urls import patterns

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    urls = 'my_app.urls'

    def setUp(self):
        super(MyTestCase, self).setUp()
        self.original_urls = my_app.urls.urlpatterns
        my_app.urls.urlpatterns += patterns(
            '',
            (r'^my/test/url/pattern$', my_view),
        )

    def tearDown(self):
        super(MyTestCase, self).tearDown()
        my_app.urls.urlpatterns = self.original_urls
```

Please note that this will not work if you omit the `urls` class attribute. This is because the urls will otherwise be cached and your monkey patching will not take effect if you run your test together with other test cases.

Comment: But why would you do this, use monkey-path as a last resort when you cannot properly declare something. Here you explicitly set 'my_app.urls' only to alter it a couple of lines later!

Comment: This is certainly not the recommended way to generally override test urls - `my_app.urls` in this case is the default app urls module, not a test specific one, and it's a hacky way to force urls reload. I just added it because I have encountered a case where monkey patching actually required far effort code than recreating a whole urls module.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't get it running with the answers above. Not even with the `override_settings`.
Found a solution which works for me. My usecase was to write some integration tests where I want to test put/post methods where I needed the urls from my app.

The main clue here is to use the **`set_urlconf`** function of `django.urls` instead of overwriting it in the class or using `override_settings`.

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse, set_urlconf

class MyTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        set_urlconf('yourapp.urls')  # yourapp is the folder where you define your root urlconf.

    def test_url_resolving_with_app_urlconf(self):
        response = self.client.put(
            path=reverse('namespace:to:your:view-name'), data=test_data
        )
```